# WHM Not Allowing To Connect To Smtp Using Root Domain

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, whm

i am trying to connect to smtp server but not able to connect .
its giving the following error.

Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "email@example.com" using 2 possible authenticators.

all password and setting are right.
think so some problem with WHM.

also when i turn Restrict outgoing SMTP to root, exim, and mailman (FKA SMTP Tweak) [?] to ON it dosent work.

but when i turn Restrict outgoing SMTP to root, exim, and mailman (FKA SMTP Tweak) [?] to off it works but send mail from localhost .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking the logs at server at path /var/log/exim_mainlog and it will give you an idea of whats happening , based on that you will have to make the changes.

Answer (score 0):

As i restarted the server all working good.